# How do I convert a String to Map<String, String> when entry values have a comma in them?

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap, substring

So to add more context, suppose I have a string (with the double-quotes included):

`"Id":"1","Name":"Bob","Notes":"Likes watching movies"`

And I want to convert it to a map:

```
{Id: 1, Name: Bob, Notes: Likes watching movies}
```

I've explored various solutions to achieve this, one of them being using the split() method to split the string by comma, and the using split() again to split each entry by colon. Although this solution works, it's not ideal. In scenarios where an entry value can have a comma, this solution can break. For instance, if my string looked like this (with the double-quotes included):

`"Id":"1","Name":"Bob","Notes":"Likes watching movies, playing video games"`

One solution I'm trying right now is iterating through the string to find the indices of the commas that are specifically preceeded by " and succeeded by ". And then incorporating the indices into the substring() method to pull out each entry. It's a work in progress, but I was wondering if there are easier solutions for this.

I also don't want to use 3rd party libraries because I want a solution that also works when run from a mobile device. My phone runs android and I don't think java compilers in the google play store are powerful enough to work with 3rd party libraries.

Would using split() with regex be a viable solution? I have some basic knowledge of regex but I can't think of how I can use it to match only the commas that separate each entry.

Comment: *"One solution I'm trying right now is iterating through the string"* - It's way better to **show the code**, instead of only talking about the code.

Comment: I don't understand the paragraph about libraries and compilers.

Comment: BTW, the string you've provided looks like JSON, but without curly braces `{ }`.

Comment: "My phone runs android and I don't think java compilers in the google play store are powerful enough to work with 3rd party libraries." This is not remotely true.  The most realistic solution is to use a third-party library, and pretty much every Android app in the Google Play Store uses third-party libraries.  Regex won't do this job, it'll be harder than that.  Just use a library.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, you can parse the String into a Map with `String::split` on `","` and `":"`. I tested this on both of the examples that you gave.

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Scratch {
    static Map<String, String> toMap(String mapAsString) {
        return Arrays.stream(mapAsString.substring(1, mapAsString.length() - 1).split("\",\"")).map(entryAsString -> entryAsString.split("\":\"")).collect(Collectors.toMap(entryAsArray -> entryAsArray[0], entryAsArray -> entryAsArray[1]));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var string0 = "\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Bob\",\"Notes\":\"Likes watching movies\"";
        var string1 = "\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Bob\",\"Notes\":\"Likes watching movies, playing video games\"";
        System.out.println(toMap(string0));
        System.out.println(toMap(string1));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{Id=1, Notes=Likes watching movies, Name=Bob}
{Id=1, Notes=Likes watching movies, playing video games, Name=Bob}
```